# Share image and text using Intent in kotlin

Tags: image, kotlin, share

I have to share the image and text of an event which is in Recyclerview. In adapter I have given the comment and share button, But i can't share the image to any member as it shows "The file format is not supported". I am getting the images from server using retrofit and the path I am receiving is "Uploads/xxx.jpg". I have used Fileprovider to share the images.Also added permission to manifest(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STOREGE). Please anyone help on this will be great thankful.

This is the share button part below:

```
mHolder.event_shareButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            val imageUri=mEvents.image
            val externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/shared_images/"
            val mDrawable = mHolder.event_image.drawable
            val bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDrawable.intrinsicWidth,mDrawable.intrinsicHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val canvas = Canvas(bmp);
            mDrawable.setBounds(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
            mDrawable.draw(canvas)

            val file = File(externalStorageDir)
            file.mkdirs()

            val fname = "/" + imageUri
            val mFile = File(file, fname!!)
            val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                context,
                "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider",
                mFile.absoluteFile
            )
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mEvents.eventname)
            shareIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*")
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send"))
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
        }
    }


})
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

provider_paths:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>

</paths>
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. What do you mean by "share"? Sounds like you are not handling a thrown exception, when you get the message "The file format is not supported" it is wrapped in an exception that has been thrown from a method you have called. It kind of tells you what the problem is. You have 2 options to resolve; check the file format is valid before trying to work with the file OR wrap the file work in a try catch (the former of these options sounds more sensible to me).

Comment: Actually I am not getting the image to share.

Comment: Could anyone help on this plz.. I don't know whether I am doing correct to share the image.

Comment: You have yet to explain what you mean by "share an image"

Comment: I would suggest fixing "The file format is not supported" before worrying about anything else

Comment: I am loading the images from server to recyclerview(mEvents in the code defines the list[position]). So on clicking the share button I have to share the particular image using intent.